# Notifications only appear on some devices

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have a function that sends notifications to the user but when I test on the Xiaomi device mi a1 they are not displayed but other applications present them without problems, since if I test on a Samsung device it works normally! Someone can help me?

**Here is my code:**

```
     public void gerarNotificacao(Context context, Intent intent, CharSequence ticker, CharSequence titulo, CharSequence descricao){
        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent p = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        builder.setTicker(ticker);
        builder.setContentTitle(titulo);
        builder.setContentText(descricao);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
        builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher_background));
        builder.setContentIntent(p);

        Notification n = builder.build();
        n.vibrate = new long[]{150, 300, 150, 600};
        n.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        nm.notify(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, n);

        try{
            Uri som = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            Ringtone toque = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, som);
            toque.play();
        }
        catch(Exception e){}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the android version of Xiaomi device?

try this function

```
    public void gerarNotificacao(Context context, Intent intent, CharSequence ticker,CharSequence titulo, CharSequence descricao){
         Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChatActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(titulo);
        notificationBuilder.setContentText(descricao);

                notificationBuilder.setSound(defaultSoundUri);


            NotificationManager notificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
        }
```